# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I am putting spring.jar file in my lib folder but still there is error like

```
 at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspInit(index_jsp.java:23)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.init(HttpJspBase.java:52)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:159)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:329)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:261)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:581)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

and webpage give me error like

> HTTP Status 500 -

How do I resolved it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [War deployment error related to classloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613605/war-deployment-error-related-to-classloading). Please do not repost your questions; edit the original post instead if needed. Or if there is a significant difference between the two, please state the difference clearly in the 2nd post :-)

Comment: @org, oops, sorry, I may have been too quick to react, mislead by the title :-(

Answer (score 17):

If you want to configure load time weaving on Tomcat, you need to place `org.springframework.instrument.tomcat.jar` into `lib` folder **of Tomcat installation directory**, as described in the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw-environments).

Otherwise, if you don't need it and accidentially used wrong `context.xml`, you need to remove `<Loader>` element from it.

Answer (score 3):

The `org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader` is now located in the `spring-instrument-tomcat.jar`, which can be downloaded from Maven Central or Spring Source.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you see an exception with something of this effect (i.e. a `ClassNotFoundException`):

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xx.xxx.class.ClassName
```

You must know that the (from JavaDoc of ClassNotFoundException):

> no definition for the class with the
>   specified name could be found.

In this case, `com.vaannila.service.UserServiceImpl` cannot be found (from error log: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vaannila.service.UserServiceImpl`).

Make sure you have the jar file included in your project (containing `com.vaanila.service.UserServiceImpl`).