# Error while running this project in tomcat6

Tags: spring, tomcat

When i am runig my project in myeclipse using tomcat6 then it will throw an error like so what should i do  this error regarding spring class but i will load all spring library from myeclipse

```
Jan 12, 2011 5:24:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0\bin;C:\Program Files\Genuitec\Common\plugins\com.genuitec.eclipse.easie.tomcat.myeclipse_8.6.0.me201007231647\tomcat\bin
Jan 12, 2011 5:24:10 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jan 12, 2011 5:24:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2559 ms
Jan 12, 2011 5:24:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jan 12, 2011 5:24:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.13
Jan 12, 2011 5:24:19 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader start
SEVERE: LifecycleException 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.createClassLoader(WebappLoader.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.start(WebappLoader.java:639)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4196)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:920)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:883)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:492)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1138)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:566)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Jan 12, 2011 5:24:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
LifecycleException:  start: :  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.start(WebappLoader.java:676)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4196)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:920)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:883)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:492)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1138)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:566)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Jan 12, 2011 5:24:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
SEVERE: Error deploying web application directory servlet
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: LifecycleException:  start: :  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:795)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:920)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:883)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:492)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1138)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:566)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Jan 12, 2011 5:24:19 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jan 12, 2011 5:24:20 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Jan 12, 2011 5:24:20 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/219  config=null
Jan 12, 2011 5:24:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 9998 ms
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615164/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-instrument-classloading-to)

Answer (score 1):

http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-28028.html

Answer (score 0):

Your Tomcat has been configured to use Spring's classloader instrumentation framework, but Spring is missing from your classpath.

You wither need to remove that instrumentation config, or add Spring to the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like one of the Spring jars is not on your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

This question is hard to answer without asking for more details... I had this (or similar) error in different situations, one of which is just solved.

If you're running the app using Eclipse's  "Run As/Run on Server" command/menu, then you could try either manually adding a spring-instrument-tomcat-.jar to the Tomcat's installation home/lib/ directory, and try again; or (if you do not actually need LTW nor  instrumentation) - check whether you have loaderClass="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader" in your project ..webapp/META-INF/context.xml and remove it..

If you're actually using Maven and running as "Run As/Maven..." from eclipse (then - tomcat6:run command; also can do from console), then it's a different story.  The following POM configuration works both for deploying on a stand-alone tomcat (if you've added the spring JAR as I described above) and embedded one:
...

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>META-INF</targetPath>
                        <directory>src/main/config</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>context.xml</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <port>8080</port>
                <path>/</path>                  
                <update>true</update>               
                <classLoaderClass>org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader</classLoaderClass>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-instrument-tomcat</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Note: the TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader and META-INF/context.xml file conflicts with the tomcat6-maven-plugin (which works when the context.xml file is not in src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml), so I had to move it to src/main/config and then let maven-war-plugin take care of it.

Cheers,
IR.